# Symfony SELECT query returns all columns, except one with relation to other table?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

DB:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aABXl.png)

Controller:

```
    $comments = $commentRepo->getPaginationPost($recordsPerPage, $offset, $id);

    dump($comments); exit;
```

Repository:

```
public function getPaginationPost($limit, $offset, $postId)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('c.postId = :postId')
        ->setParameter('postId', $postId)
        ->andWhere('c.replyTo = 0')
        ->orderBy('c.dateAdded', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults($limit)
        ->setFirstResult($offset)
        ->getQuery();

    return $qb->getArrayResult();
}
```

Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Tests\Fixtures\Person;

/**
 * Comment
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="comment")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CommentRepository")
 */
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $person;
```

Well the result from dump is full data, except column person (person_id). Any ideas why this is happend? Person column is with relation oneToMany, all of them have getters and setters.

Result from `dump()`:

```
ArticleController.php on line 183:
array:10 [
  0 => array:5 [
    "id" => 168
    "content" => "Лошо е"
    "dateAdded" => DateTime {#7320
      +"date": "2019-01-09 11:02:35.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "UTC"
    }
    "replyTo" => 0
    "postId" => 8
  ]
  1 => array:5 [
    "id" => 167
    "content" => "нееее лошооо"
    "dateAdded" => DateTime {#7321
      +"date": "2019-01-08 16:07:09.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "UTC"
    }
    "replyTo" => 0
    "postId" => 8
  ]
] 
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't joined the entities in your query.

```
public function getPaginationPost($limit, $offset, $postId)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
               ->join('c.person', 'p')    // <--- see this
               ->addSelect('p')
               ->where('c.postId = :postId')
               ->setParameter('postId', $postId)
               ->andWhere('c.replyTo = 0')
               ->orderBy('c.dateAdded', 'DESC')
               ->setMaxResults($limit)
               ->setFirstResult($offset)
               ->getQuery();

    return $qb->getArrayResult();
}
```

Comment: The result is same

Comment: It should have ` ->addSelect('p')` also, edit your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I thought the idea is Symfony to do this automatically when you got Relation, like oneToMany ..

Comment: I edited my answer. This can't be done automatically to avoid issues in bidirectionnals relations